# Серверная часть для мобильного сервиса

Tags: php, c#, node.js, веб-служба

Господа, тут у меня беда приключилась. Знакомый делает мобильное-приложение и просит запилить серверную часть. Приложение  представляет собой в общем доску объявлений с загрузками картинок. Сам-то я посредственный PHP-программист, но когда то ковырял Nodejs и даже разбирал "для себя" веб-сервисы Asp. Собственно из этого надо выбрать на чем делать: кошерен ли PHP, годен ли NodeJS или сгодится Asp, по вашему опыту?

Comment: Все из перечисленного вполне подойдет. Берите что лучше знаете.

Comment: Смотрите на возможности размещения сервера: где Вы хотите размещать серверную часть приложения - на хостинге, на виртуалке, на домашнем сервере с выделенным адресом, на выделенном сервере в датацентре, на собственном серверном кластере. В общем, от бюджета отталкивайтесь. Дёшево, быстро и проверенно - PHP. Прогрессивно, быстро, интересно - NodeJS. Для старта PHP будет более чем достаточно - всё необходимое, согласно описанию, он может.

Answer (score 1):

Я не веб-программист, мне больше по душе пришлось PHP. Любой веб-хостинг поддержит, легко перенести будет, меньше мороки по запуску и прочее, язык понятен. Данные передавались через JSON между клиентом и сервером.

Comment: В плане доступности и переносимости, а так же лёгкости в поиске сторонних разработчиков - PHP безусловно пока что фаворит. Но если необходимо что-то более специфичное - можно взять что угодно, но учесть тот факт, что может понадобиться персональный виртуальный сервер (где-нибудь в облаке). Для PHP же хватит и самого дешёвого хостинга. Тут только уже учесть придётся то, что могут возникнуть некоторые ограничения по производительности сервера и накладки из-за нагрузки "соседей" по хостингу.

Comment: @DimXenon, да но у него моб.приложение "доска объявлений" судя по вопросу.. ему вполне хватит PHP учитывая что меньше заморочек для начинающего. Когда раскрутятся уже допетрят, куда двигаться и что им надо.

Comment: Для старта, конечно хватит, согласен.

Comment: @IvanZakirov вы хотели написать "ему хватит и *шаред хостинга*", а не РНР. А то получается двусмысленность. Фейсбук, в каком-то роде - тоже доска объявлений. И РНР для нее вполне хватает.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что выбор платформы зависит от конкретной ситуации.

Если поджимают сроки -- используйте то, что знаете лучше всего, знаете лучше всего PHP -- пишите на нем, если нет, а тем более есть желание изучить что-то еще, возьмите это "что-то еще". Упомянутая Вами Node.js вполне подойдет для такого проекта, как, кстати, и ASP.NET.

Касательно поддержки веб-хостингом: обычно бекенды для мобильных приложений на shared-хостингах не размещают, их размещают в облаках, VPS, VDS и т.п., а там в общем-то границ в выборе платформ обычно нет.

Также, посоветуйте товарищу обратить внимание на различные BaaS (Backend as a Service).

Comment: Ну будет однозначно ВПС как минимум. Обычный шаред хостинг на элементарном чате  как правило загибается.

Comment: Я бы в этом случае взял, наверное, Node.js.